# Javascript array of objects assistance

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to do a rating algorithm. Initially the values are all like this:

```
[
  { rating: 1, amount: 252 },
  { rating: 2, amount: 124 },
  { rating: 3, amount: 40 },
  { rating: 4, amount: 29 },
  { rating: 5, amount: 30 },
];
```

Where `rating` is the value and `amount` is the amount of people who have left a 4 star rating for example

What I am trying to do is take these values and calculate the following to get the rating

```
(5*252 + 4*124 + 3*40 + 2*29 + 1*33) / (252+124+40+29+33) = 4.11
```

So my question is what is the best way to take the array of `initialized` objects and calculate the rating as I have done above with basic math.

Comment: why not `1 * 252 + 2 * 124 + ...`?

Comment: how would I do that in code?

Comment: Unrelated, but I don’t understand your rating calculation at all unless the ratings are inverted.

Comment: if you have lots of one stars, the average should go to one ...?

Comment: Yes you're right thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and collect product and amount for getting the average.

```js
const 
    data = [{ rating: 1, amount: 252 }, { rating: 2, amount: 124 }, { rating: 3, amount: 40 }, { rating: 4, amount: 29 }, { rating: 5, amount: 30 }],
    { sum, count } = data.reduce((r, { rating, amount }) => {
        r.sum += rating * amount;
        r.count += amount;
        return r;
    }, { sum: 0, count: 0 }),
    average = sum /count;

console.log(average);
```

Comment: This algorithm won't give the answer 4.11

Answer (score -1):

first your calculated value above seems to have some problem it should be

```
(5*252 + 4*124 + 3*40 + 2*29 + 1*30) / (252+124+40+29+30) = 4.13
```

according to the array your provided.

```js
const arr = [
      { rating: 1, amount: 252 },
      { rating: 2, amount: 124 },
      { rating: 3, amount: 40 },
      { rating: 4, amount: 29 },
      { rating: 5, amount: 30 },
    ];
const len = arr.length;
var r, a, p,amt = 0, sum = 0, j =0;
    
for (var i = len -1; i >= 0; i -- ) {
  r = arr[i].rating;
  while( j < len) {
    a = arr[j].amount;
    j++;
    p = r * a;
    break;
  }
  sum = sum + a;
  amt = amt + p;
}

var value = amt / sum;
console.log(value);
```